# Pocketsphinx android demo is working great on Android 4.3 and below. But it crashes in Android 4.4 and above

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

The code runs great on all Android devices running 4.0 - 4.3. However on devices running Android 4.4 and above, KWS_Search starts successfully but the application crashes the moment I say "activate speech" giving the following error.

```
02-06 20:13:40.228: I/cmusphinx(29758): INFO: fsg_search.c(843): 74 frames, 477 HMMs (6/fr), 2534 senones (34/fr), 23 history entries (0/fr)
02-06 20:13:40.235: I/SpeechRecognizer(29758): Stop recognition
02-06 20:13:40.235: I/SpeechRecognizer(29758): Start recognition "wakeup"
02-06 20:13:40.244: D/bt(29758): subclass 
02-06 20:13:40.256: I/cmusphinx(29758): INFO: pocketsphinx.c(863): Writing raw audio log file: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.BuildingBlocks.codigo/files/sync/000000007.raw
02-06 20:13:40.459: A/libc(29758): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x89280000 in tid 30022 (Thread-1944)
```

I get Fatal signal 11 when a device runs out of memory usually if I use very high resolution graphics

I searched the internet and found that Google introduced HotKeywords in Android 4.4 where the phone is constantly listening to sounds. Sometimes it works if I wait for 60 seconds before saying the KEYPHRASE. Sometimes it doesnot work and the my app crashes. Below is my complete code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
super.onCreate(state);

// Prepare the data for UI
captions = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
captions.put(KWS_SEARCH, R.string.kws_caption);
//captions.put(MENU_SEARCH, R.string.menu_caption);
captions.put(DIGITS_SEARCH, R.string.digits_caption);
//captions.put(FORECAST_SEARCH, R.string.forecast_caption);
setContentView(R.layout.sphinx_voice);
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.speech))
        .setText("Preparing the recognizer");
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.speech)).setTextSize(23);
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.deactivate)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.listening)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

// Recognizer initialization is a time-consuming and it involves IO,
// so we execute it in async task

new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Exception>() {
    @Override
    protected Exception doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Assets assets = new Assets(SphinxVoice.this);
            File assetDir = assets.syncAssets();
            setupRecognizer(assetDir);
            load=2;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return e;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Exception result) {
        if (load==2)
        {
        if (result != null) {
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.speech))
                    .setText("Failed to init recognizer " + result);
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.speech)).setTextSize(23);
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.deactivate)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.listening)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.deactivate)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.listening)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }   
        }
    }
}.execute();
}

@Override
public void onPartialResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
if (text.contains("left"))
{
    ((CodigoApplication)SphinxVoice.this.getApplicationContext()).sendMessage("DLXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
     switchSearch(DIGITS_SEARCH);
     ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setText("Executing Left");
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.listening)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.deactivate)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}else if (text.contains("right"))
{
    ((CodigoApplication)SphinxVoice.this.getApplicationContext()).sendMessage("DRXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
     switchSearch(DIGITS_SEARCH);
     ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setText("Executing Right");
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.listening)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.deactivate)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}else if (text.contains("forward"))
{
    ((CodigoApplication)SphinxVoice.this.getApplicationContext()).sendMessage("DFXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
     switchSearch(DIGITS_SEARCH);
     ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setText("Executing Forward");
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.listening)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.deactivate)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}else if (text.contains("back"))
{
    ((CodigoApplication)SphinxVoice.this.getApplicationContext()).sendMessage("DBXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    switchSearch(DIGITS_SEARCH);
     ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setText("Executing Back");
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.listening)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.deactivate)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}else if (text.contains("stop"))
{
    ((CodigoApplication)SphinxVoice.this.getApplicationContext()).sendMessage("DYXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
     switchSearch(DIGITS_SEARCH);
     ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setText("Stop");
     ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.deactivate)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.listening)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}else if (text.contains("deactivate"))
{
     ((CodigoApplication)SphinxVoice.this.getApplicationContext()).sendMessage("DYXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
     switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
     ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.deactivate)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.listening)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}else if (text.equals(KEYPHRASE))
{
      switchSearch(DIGITS_SEARCH);
     ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.deactivate)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.listening)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else{
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setText(text);
    }
}
@Override
public void onResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setText("");

if (hypothesis != null) {
    String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
    if (text.contains("left"))
    {
        ((CodigoApplication)SphinxVoice.this.getApplicationContext()).sendMessage("DLXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
         switchSearch(DIGITS_SEARCH);
         ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setText("Executing Left");
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.listening)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.deactivate)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }else if (text.contains("right"))
    {
        ((CodigoApplication)SphinxVoice.this.getApplicationContext()).sendMessage("DRXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
         switchSearch(DIGITS_SEARCH);
         ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setText("Executing Right");
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.listening)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.deactivate)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }else if (text.contains("forward"))
    {
        ((CodigoApplication)SphinxVoice.this.getApplicationContext()).sendMessage("DFXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
         switchSearch(DIGITS_SEARCH);
         ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setText("Executing Forward");
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.listening)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.deactivate)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }else if (text.contains("back"))
    {
        ((CodigoApplication)SphinxVoice.this.getApplicationContext()).sendMessage("DBXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        switchSearch(DIGITS_SEARCH);
         ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setText("Executing Back");
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.listening)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.deactivate)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }else if (text.contains("stop"))
    {
        ((CodigoApplication)SphinxVoice.this.getApplicationContext()).sendMessage("DYXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
         switchSearch(DIGITS_SEARCH);
         ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setText("Stop");
         ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.deactivate)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.listening)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }else if (text.contains("deactivate"))
    {
         ((CodigoApplication)SphinxVoice.this.getApplicationContext()).sendMessage("DYXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
         switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
         ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.deactivate)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.listening)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }else if (text.equals(KEYPHRASE))
    {
        switchSearch(DIGITS_SEARCH);
         ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.deactivate)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.listening)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else{
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setText(text);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {

    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.listening)).setText("Listening...");
}

@Override
public void onEndOfSpeech() {

}

private void switchSearch(String searchName) {
recognizer.stop();
recognizer.startListening(searchName);
String caption = getResources().getString(captions.get(searchName));
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.speech)).setText(caption);
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.speech)).setTextSize(23);
}

private void setupRecognizer(File assetsDir) {
File modelsDir = new File(assetsDir, "models");
recognizer = defaultSetup()
        .setAcousticModel(new File(modelsDir, "hmm/en-us-semi"))
        .setDictionary(new File(modelsDir, "dict/cmu07a.dic"))
        .setRawLogDir(assetsDir).setKeywordThreshold(1f-80f)
        .getRecognizer();
recognizer.addListener(this);

// Create keyword-activation search.
recognizer.addKeyphraseSearch(KWS_SEARCH, KEYPHRASE);
// Create grammar-based searches.
Log.d("voicelog",modelsDir.getAbsolutePath());
File robbyGrammar = new File(modelsDir, "grammar/robby.gram");
Log.d("voicelog",robbyGrammar.getAbsolutePath());
recognizer.addGrammarSearch(DIGITS_SEARCH, robbyGrammar);
}

@Override 
public void onBackPressed() { 
        recognizer.cancel();
        SphinxVoice.this.finish();
    } 
}
```

Below is the robby.gram file

```
#JSGF V1.0;
```

grammar robby;

= deactivate speech|
          left      |
          right     |
          forward   |
          back      |
          stop ;

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check for `hypothesis != null` in `onPartialResult` method before calling `getHypstr()`.